# aliases don't seem to work in vue storybook

Tags: webpack, vue.js, storybook

I'm using [storybook for vue](https://storybook.js.org/basics/guide-vue/) to generate a styleguide and I would like to add some aliases for 'src' folder so i can easily reference components and scss files.

So i added `webpack.config.js` file under `.storybook`:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = (baseConfig, env, defaultConfig) => {
  defaultConfig.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
    include: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/scss")
  });

  defaultConfig.resolve.extensions.push(".scss");
  defaultConfig.resolve.alias = {
    ...defaultConfig.resolve.alias,
    "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "../src"),
    "~": path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/scss")
  };

  return defaultConfig;
};
```

But when i try to reference an scss file i get an error:

> Module build failed: @import "~/main"; ^
>         File to import not found or unreadable: ~/main.

I also tried with `~main` but still the same.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually don't know why (would be happy to learn if somebody knows), but you have to prepend `~` before `scss` / `sass` imports that use webpack aliases. Because of that, your `~` example won't work. But the `@` should.

```
@import '~@/some-file';
```

Comment: `~` symbol means import is global in `scss`/`sass` syntax